# Real time credit card holder authorization & verification for US merchant

Tags: payment-gateway

In my project ,I want to implement real time verification of card holder during transaction processing using asp.net (C#) in order to provide higher level of security and avoid fraud transaction. I am doing R&D on this to have most prominent solution which will support for all types of credit card such Visa, Master Card,American Express, Discover etc.

please refer below scenario :

1) Consider a use case where I am on a family holiday in a foreign country. I give my card to a relative for doing some shopping. He pays using the card and provides his own name in the billing info.i.e card was not stolen but allowed to use intentionally to another user.

2) Consider another scenario where my friend had stolen my credit card details and done transactions successfully after this,when my card was charged I came to know that this particular transaction was not done by me but done by some one else without my permission. (i.e Unauthorized Person) .

Please suggest which payment getaway should I use in order to fulfill my requirement for US merchant account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If an unauthorized user has all the credit card details and other personal information necessary to make a purchase, it's not easy to stop them from doing so.

You could implement some sort of [Dynamic Knowledge Based Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge-based_authentication#Dynamic_KBA)  as part of the transaction process - although this would not necessarily make for great user experience, as most of your users probably aren't accustom to having to go through a process like this to make an online purchase.

There are several vendors that offer Knowledge Based Authentication services as described above - [LexisNexis is one example](http://www.lexisnexis.com/risk/products/knowledge-based-authentication.aspx).